# intent to open browser not working on tabhost

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost

I want to open the browser when user click on a tab, this is the code i'm using

```
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            if (tabId.equals(tabSpecdiwan)) {
                String diwan = "http://j.mp/RIShjZ";
                Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                a.setData(Uri.parse(diwan));
                startActivity(a);
            } 
            else   {}

          }
```

update:
i updated the code with an else if statement to show alert dialogue if (!tabId.equals(tabSpecdiwan)) (note the "!" before tabId) and the else if statement is working whenever i click on ANY tab including tabSpecdiwan..

Comment: This look right. Is `tabId.equals(tabSpecdiwan) == true`? Make a `System.out.println("hi there");` in the else.

Comment: Do you get anything in the LogCat?

Comment: Dont use tab host, it is better to use action bar with tabs.

Comment: Why not print out what `tabId` is, so you can actually see what you are getting?

Comment: isn't this feature for Android 4+ ?

Comment: @CommonsWare please answer so i can accept & close the question

Comment: You are welcome to supply your own answer. Since you are the only one who knows how you fixed it, you are the only one who can supply the answer.

Comment: alright, due to my reputation is less than 10 i wont be able to answer my question for 6 hours..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after many tries to understand what's the problem, @CommonsWare came with an idea to see where the problem is comming from, so i built an else if statement (please refer to my update) and set the content of the alert dialogue to show the tabId .setMessage(tabId), the problem was that I wrote tabSpecdiwan instead of "tabSpecdiwan"

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

final TabSpec tabSpecdiwan = tabHost
.newTabSpec("tabSpecddiwann")
```